# How to solve the following system of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

> If $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are the general solution of the system of the differential equations: $$\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dt}+2y=\sin t $$ $$\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dt}-x-y=0$$ Then which of the following conditions holds for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$? ($a$ is any arbitrary constant)
>
> (a) $x(t)+y(t)=ae^t$
>
> (b) $x(t)+y(t)=a\sin t$
>
> (c) $x(t)-y(t)=ae^{-t}$
>
> (d) $x(t)-y(t)=ae^t+\sin t$

We can write the above system of equations as: $$Dx+(D+2)y=\sin t \label{eq:1}$$ and $$(D-1)x+(D-1)y=0$$

Now, how to solve for $x$ and $y$ ?
The solution says solving above equation for $x$ and $y$ to get:

> $(D-1)x=-\frac{\cos t - \sin t}{2}$ and $(D-1)y=\frac{\cos t - \sin t}{2}$

How to solve please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: The second equation reads $\frac{d}{dt}(x+y)=(x+y)$. You can solve this for $x+y$ and then solve the first equation.

Comment: The given solution is not the most general. Did you forget the initial conditions ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have edited the question, there are no initial conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying the $1$st equation by $(D-1)$ and the $2$nd one by $D$ and then subtracting, we get
\begin{align}
\{(D-1)(D+2)-D(D-1)\}y&=\sin t\\
\implies (D-1)y&=\dfrac12\sin t\\
\end{align}
So the auxiliary equation is
$m-1=0\implies m=1$
So C.F is $y_c=ce^t$
For P.I, \begin{align}
y_p&=\dfrac{1}{D-1}\dfrac12 \sin t\\
&=-\dfrac14 \sin t\\
\end{align}
So the general solution is $y=ce^t-\dfrac14 \sin t$
Now $Dy=ce^t-\dfrac14 \cos t$
So from the $2$nd equation, we get
\begin{align}
&(D-1)x+ce^t-\dfrac14 \cos t-ce^t+\dfrac14 \sin t=0\\
\implies &(D-1)x=\dfrac14(\cos t-\sin t)\\
\end{align}
The auxiliary equation is
$m-1=0\implies m=1$
So C.F is $x_c=de^t$
For P.I, \begin{align}
x_p&=\dfrac{1}{D-1}\dfrac14(\cos t-\sin t)\\
&=\dfrac18 (\sin t-\cos t)\\
\end{align}
So the general solution is $x=de^t+\dfrac18 (\sin t-\cos t)$

Answer (score 1):

The second equation is

$$\dot x+\dot y=x+y$$ and $x+y=ce^t$.

Then the first says

$$ce^t+2y=\sin t.$$

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you copied correectly the system ? Maybe it's a minus sign instead of a positive one in one of the differential equation ?

Because if you substract both DE you get:

$$x+3y=\sin t $$

Use this to solve the seond differential equation:
$$x'+y'=x+y$$